# abs_path with the home directory

Tags: perl

I created a perl script that uses `abs_path` but it doesn't correctly handle the home directory (represented by '~')

EG if I try to call `abs_path("~/mystuff");`

it returns `undef`

Can I make `abs_path` correctly handle the home directory? And if not, is there an alternative I can use?

Comment: Are you referring to the `abs_path` in [Cwd](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Cwd)?

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::HomeDir;

print File::HomeDir->my_home;
```

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed there's a CPAN module to do this! Good job!

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `abs_path` doesn't handle it correctly is that "~" is a **shell** construct. Perl doesn't know anything about what "~" means - it literally treats it as "a directory named 'tilde'(~) under current working directory".

Any program to which "~" is supplied as a parameter would actually get a real directory path from shell instead.

To be able to use home directories from Perl, on Unix you can use `$ENV{HOME}` instead of "~" for your own home directory; or for other users use `(getpwnam($user))[7]`; there's no clean cross-platform way to do either.

A second approach is to use shell for dirty work in a system call:

```
my $expanded_home_dir = `cd ~/mydir/; pwd`;
```

**UPDATE:**

First, a very good recipe for outright replacement of tilde-home-strings is in "Perl Cookbook" (2d ed), ch. 7.3 "Expanding tildes in filenames".

Second, as daxim mentioned in comments, since Perl 5.6, `CORE::glob()` is actually automatically replaced with `File::Glob::bsd_glob()` **which supports POSIX's `GLOB_TILDE` flag** and therefore can expand tildes for you.

Interestingly enough, both bsd_glob (in C code, as per Perlmonks), and `File::HomeDir` mentioned wisely by Andrew Clark, use precisely the same logic underneath as the Cookbook's recipe 7.3 (`$ENV{HOME}||$ENV{LOGDIR}||(getpwnam($<))[7]`) for Unix environments.

Comment: @daxim - IIRC, glob only started supporting this since 5.6 (my excuse for not remembering this is that I sadly deal a lot with 5.005).